# This strange spiral creature grew up in my cup of water after night

Tags: species-identification

This grew up in my water cup over night!

1. Length ~ 12mm
2. Form - spiral made of dark dots
3. It does not move
4. Growing slowly

Can some one help identify it?

[image: strange spiral creature]

Comment: I would guess these are eggs of some animal. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Can you give us a location as well?

Comment: Yes, of course! https://www.google.com/maps/@46.3494507,48.0312648,332m/data=!3m1!1e3

Comment: Wow, what a precise location :D I didn't know that there was a city with such a name, only knew the fur with this name! For how much time that speak would grow? Did it happen something afterwards?

Comment: It was expanding for 20-30 hours, then almost completely disappeared in water.

Comment: See my comment on this [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/77971/32892)

Comment: Definitely eggs since it appeared so quickly. Caddisflies (Trichoptera) lay their eggs in spirals within a slimy blob, but some searching made me see that other animals do too. Like this https://bugguide.net/node/view/641162 that apparantly comes from midges. Perhaps someone else can come closer!

Comment: @picapicaThank you! We have a lot of Caddisflies and Chironominaes here, great guess!

Comment: It appears like the egg mass of some Chironominae species. At least searching "Chironomus eggs" returns visually similar images. @picapica can you post an answer?

Comment: See this [SO](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/80557/32892) question for an answer to a related question, which points to *Chironomous* egg masses.