# Identify this organism I found in my food

Tags: species-identification

I found this thing floating in my orange juice this morning.
I pulled it out and it appears to be some sort of protozoa or something. It's about a quarter the size of my pinky nail. Was not moving at all.

Should I be worried about this? Either way I will be notifying the store. Location is Okinawa, Japan.

[image: thing1]
[image: thing2]

Comment: A flatworm (Planaria) perhaps?

Comment: [This](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/74125/32892) appears to be the same organism, and is (also) unanswered.

Comment: See my comment on this [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/77971/32892)

Comment: See this [SO](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/80557/32892) question for an answer to a related question, which points to *Chironomous* egg masses.