# Can you help me identify this "thing"?

Tags: species-identification

I found these "things" by chance on my wild strawberries which I grow in my organic garden. Basically, some strawberries are completely covered with them.

[image: photo showing the "thing"]

They're transparent, they have dots equally aligned and they don't move. I've tried searching for transparent slugs and worms and also faeces but to no avail.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the same thing appears in these two other questions which are unanswered: [thing one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/77097/32892) [thing two](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/74125/32892) At this point given the variety of places they have been seen they must be some kind of egg, but surely someone with expertise will eventually tell us.

Comment: Alright, I searched for "gelatinous insect eggs", found a similar image, and encountered a 3-part discussion of these things that begins with [part 1](http://askanaturalist.com/what-is-this-bright-green-string-of-eggs-part-1/).   It's a fair amount to read but I think it is your "thing".

Comment: Where do you live and how big are these millipedes(just a hunch).Do they have legs because if they don't you can tell they're not millipedes and centipedes

Comment: @BryanHanson I don't think theyre the same thing these have a shape and look so much like millipedes but once OP replies it will become clear

Comment: @BryanHanson I did the same search as you and after looking at many images I guess I found the species (I am not sure, though). It appears like the egg mass of [Chironomus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chironomus).

Comment: @WYSIWYG I think you might actually got it right. I just google'd "chironomus egg mass" and I'm getting back images very similar to mine. Chironomus appears to be a non-biting version of mosquitoes (by how similar they look to an average Joe) and now when we're talking about it, in the area where I live there are mosquitoes but during summer time at night there might be hundreds if not thousands of mosquitoes/chironomuses attracted to lights nearby. I thought they're all mosquitoes but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @WYSIWYG At the very end of the 3 part blog post I referenced above, it come down to caddisfly eggs vs chironomous eggs, with this important distinction, quoting now: "chironomid eggs are nearly always elongated or oval shaped. Caddisfly eggs, on the other hand, are nearly always spherical."  Not all the pictures on SO are clear, but in those that are it seems like the eggs are elongated, so I think you are correct about Chironomous.  I think you should post that as an answer, and also post a reference back to your answer here on the SO questions I linked to above.  Great work!

Comment: @BryanHanson I think **you** should post an answer. I believe you know about this topic better. I am not an expert on this field. My research was just some google searches :P

Comment: It appears like the egg mass of Chironomus.

Answer (score 1):

First, I am no expert on this topic, I am simply synthesizing several different sources of information along with the very good work of others.  Since the "thing" featured in this question has appeared elsewhere, it deserves an answer.

These appear to be eggs of *Chironomous* midges ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chironomus)).  This conclusion is based largely on reading the three-part blog by Tom of askanaturalist.com 
[Part 1](http://askanaturalist.com/what-is-this-bright-green-string-of-eggs-part-1/), [Part 2](http://askanaturalist.com/what-is-this-bright-green-string-of-eggs-part-2/), [Part 3](http://askanaturalist.com/what-is-this-bright-green-string-of-eggs-part-3/) which is very thorough.  In the last part of that blog, it is stated "chironomid eggs are nearly always elongated or oval shaped. Caddisfly eggs, on the other hand, are nearly always spherical." Looking at the pictures here and on the other SO questions ([here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/74125/32892) and [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/77097/32892)) it appears that the eggs are indeed elongated rather than spherical.  Hence they are apparently *Chironomous* midge eggs.

Comment: I doubt it can be Chironomidae eggs. These midges live aquatic, or at least in very wet conditions. "On wild strawberries" is way to dry i think.

Comment: This link supports that Chironomidae live in aquatic or in very wet conditions. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.eje.cz/pdfs/eje/2003/04/01.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwilj9-a_vLfAhVHaFAKHWpEC-EQFjACegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw0IYCx7tDciVnLlY6JT_ajV